Gradle with parallel mode run one module's tests at the end exclusively
I have repo with about 10 modules. There are some dependencies between them, but I don't think it should have affect on unit tests of these modules.
I run unit tests in gradle with parallel mode and see that tests of all modules are really run in parallel except one. And this one has the most complex and longest tests. All modules except this one run their tests in about 1 minute. And this one takes about 3 minutes.
So I want exactly this module to run in parallel. But I have no idea how to command this to gradle. It seems it has its own opinion.
Are there any workarounds to fix it?

It seems that default number of threads for parallel execution wasn't enough for this project.
I set org.gradle.parallel.threads=16 and problem was solved. It works for Gradle version 8.5.
For newer version use org.gradle.workers.max. But they say that default value for this parameter is the amount of cores, so you don't need to set it explicitly.
